# Google Analytics report on the website

Tags: 7, google-analytics

Is there a way of making the google analytics available for previewing on the drupal 7 site?

Answer (score 2):

Try [Google Analytics Reports](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports) module.

> Graphical reports include a dashboard widget for admins, a small
>   path-based report in blocks, and a full path-based report.
>
> Prerequisites are the [Google Charts API](http://drupal.org/project/chart) module and the [OAth](http://drupal.org/project/oauth)
>   module. Do not forget to set the module’s permissions about who has
>   access to the reports.

Comment: Thanks so much for that @monymirza
I've installed all three of those modules but am getting this error message:
DrupalOAuthClient requires the PHP cURL library. (Currently using OAuth cURL library not found)
Is this where I am supposed to get the php curl library from and if so, how? :S http://php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php

Comment: are you working locally? using wamp??

Comment: Locally @monymirza
Not wamp though.

Comment: which server using u r?

Comment: Sorry, linux server @monymirza

Comment: hmmm. i think u r using Ubuntu OS...

Comment: How do I check to see if I'm using ubunty? I am not aware that I am using it ... (Someone else setup the environment for me) @monymirza

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7471/discussion-between-monymirza-and-kine456)

Comment: I can't log into the chat :( @monymirza

Comment: @schnippy
would you happen to know what my issue is?